# Events not loading on first page load but works after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, turbo-rails

I am creating an app called Employee Management System using **Rails 7**. To add an employee, I have created a form. Here I have used nested-form-fields gem for adding contacts of employee. The problem is when the form is loaded the first time, when I want to add or remove the contact field, it redirects to the same form. But when I refresh the page, it starts working without any issue. Even fields added or removed get reflected in the database. It only creates this issue when create or update employee page is loaded first time.
What I have found is when I click the link to add employee and the form opens. The events are not loaded in html. As we can see in below image near body tag:

[image]

But after refresh, events are loaded:
[image]

I have seen js.coffee file in gem folder but that is too advanced for a beginner like me. The code there looks like this:

```js
window.nested_form_fields or= {}

nested_form_fields.bind_nested_forms_links = () ->
  $('body').off("click", '.add_nested_fields_link')
  $('body').on 'click', '.add_nested_fields_link', (event, additional_data) ->
    $link = $(this)
    object_class = $link.data('object-class')
    association_path = $link.data('association-path')
    added_index = $(".nested_#{association_path}").length
    $.event.trigger("fields_adding.nested_form_fields",{object_class: object_class, added_index: added_index, association_path: association_path, additional_data: additional_data});
    if $link.data('scope')
      $template = $("#{$link.data('scope')} ##{association_path}_template")
    else
      $template = $("##{association_path}_template")
    target = $link.data('insert-into')

    template_html = $template.html()

    # insert association indexes
    index_placeholder = "__#{association_path}_index__"
    template_html = template_html.replace(new RegExp(index_placeholder,"g"), added_index)
    # look for replacements in user defined code and substitute with the index
    template_html = template_html.replace(new RegExp("__nested_field_for_replace_with_index__","g"), added_index)

    # replace child template div tags with script tags to avoid form submission of templates
    $parsed_template = $(template_html)
    $child_templates = $parsed_template.closestChild('.form_template')
    $child_templates.each () ->
      $child = $(this)
      $child.replaceWith($("<script id='#{$child.attr('id')}' type='text/html' />").html($child.html()))

    if target?
      $('#' + target).append($parsed_template)
    else
      $template.before( $parsed_template )
    $parsed_template.trigger("fields_added.nested_form_fields", {object_class: object_class, added_index: added_index, association_path: association_path, event: event, additional_data: additional_data});
    false

  $('body').off("click", '.remove_nested_fields_link')
  $('body').on 'click', '.remove_nested_fields_link', ->
    $link = $(this)
    return false unless $.rails == undefined || $.rails.allowAction($link)
    return false if $link.attr('disabled')
    object_class = $link.data('object-class')
    delete_association_field_name = $link.data('delete-association-field-name')
    removed_index = parseInt(delete_association_field_name.match('(\\d+\\]\\[_destroy])')[0].match('\\d+')[0])
    $.event.trigger("fields_removing.nested_form_fields",{object_class: object_class, delete_association_field_name: delete_association_field_name, removed_index: removed_index });
    $nested_fields_container = $link.parents(".nested_fields").first()
    delete_field = $nested_fields_container.find("input[type='hidden'][name='#{delete_association_field_name}']")
    if delete_field.length > 0
      delete_field.val('1')
    else
      $nested_fields_container.before "<input type='hidden' name='#{delete_association_field_name}' value='1' />"
    $nested_fields_container.hide()
    $nested_fields_container.find('input[required]:hidden, select[required]:hidden, textarea[required]:hidden').removeAttr('required')
    $nested_fields_container.trigger("fields_removed.nested_form_fields",{object_class: object_class, delete_association_field_name: delete_association_field_name, removed_index: removed_index});
    false

$(document).on "page:change turbolinks:load", ->
    nested_form_fields.bind_nested_forms_links()

jQuery ->
    nested_form_fields.bind_nested_forms_links()


#
# * jquery.closestchild 0.1.1
# *
# * Author: Andrey Mikhaylov aka lolmaus
# * Email: lolmaus@gmail.com
# *
#

$.fn.closestChild = (selector) ->
  $children = undefined
  $results = undefined
  $children = @children()
  return $() if $children.length is 0
  $results = $children.filter(selector)
  if $results.length > 0
    $results
  else
    $children.closestChild selector
```

Is there anything that can be changed to resolve this issue? Please help!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After working ahead on my app for 2 days, same issue came when I added jquery to application.js for adding a checkbox that makes Permanent address and local address same. So I came to conclusion that the issue is not because of gem but some other reason. So I googled and found that turbolink is the main culprit. After searching in turbo-rails github repository found the issue in 'closed' category. By adding a simple line to my head section in application.html.erb, got read of the problem. Line is:

```
<meta name="turbo-visit-control" content="reload">
```

Though, there is a problem. After adding this line, flash messages disappeared because of reload. So I googled again to find out a a better way. Removed this line, and in application.js, changed

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
```

to

```
import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
Turbo.session.drive = false`
```

This I found in turbo-rails [readme.md](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails#navigate-with-turbo-drive).
And flash messages reappeared with no need to refresh the page.

Comment: Thank you! The latter worked like a charm (Rails 7.0.4 + esbuild). The former did not work well in my case for some reason.

Comment: this "works" for me, but is very delayed. i have some javascript that removes some elements from the page and it takes 1-2 seconds for them to go away after the page load, on a local server.

Comment: Thank you!  I searched FOREVER for this.