# Bootstrap 5.1 not working in JSBundling Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, esbuild, import-maps

**2023-01-09 – SOLVED**

I started using the default Rails template, and now I want to use Bootstrap v5.1 with Rails. I've removed Importmap-Rails and proceeded with adding JSBundling-Rails and CSSBundling-Rails. The styling works properly, but none of the Bootstrap JavaScript commands seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

## Reproduction from `rails new`

```
rails new Xyz --css=bootstrap --javascript=esbuild && cd Xyz/ && ./bin/setup && git add . && git commit -m "initial commit"
```

```
rails generate controller Articles &&
echo "hello world" > app/views/articles/index.erb &&
sed -i '' -e  's/# root "articles#index"/root "articles#index"/g' config/routes.rb && 
git add . && git commit -m "generates Articles controller"
```

add to this file the default bootstrap nav:
**2023-01-09 – SOLVED—-- this is the old Bootstrap 4 markup which is why it wasn't working for me**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

clobber & setup
`rake assets:clobber && ./bin/setup && yarn install && bundle install`

then run `./bin/dev`

Result: (no js interactions work)

[image]

Expected Result: (JS interactions work)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When migrating from Importmap to JSBundling + CSSBundling, make sure that you remove the remnant files. Delete `config/importmap.rb` and `bin/importmap`.

There will also be some remnants containing Hotwire Turbo and Hotwire Stimulus. If you're not planning to use them, delete `app/javascript/controllers` and clear the lines inside of `app/javascript/application.js`. If in case, you want the hotwire libraries, first add jsbundling-rails and cssbundling-rails to the Gemfile. Complete their setup first using `rails javascript:install:[esbuild|rollup|webpack]` and `rails css:install:bootstrap`

There might be some conflict in `bin/dev`, but I haven't noticed anything different. So you can either discard, or keep the conflicted version of the file.

Most of the required files will be auto-generated, and lines auto-appended in pre-existing files, but if Bootstrap v5.1 still isn't working in rails, with JSBundling and CSSBundling:

- Make sure that:

  ```js
  import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
  ```

  has been added to the `app/javascript/application.js` file.
- See if `app/assets/stylesheets` has `*.scss` (could be `application.bootstrap.scss` or `application.scss`, doesn't matter as long as the same name is provided in `package.json`), and the content inside is:

  ```css
  @import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
  @import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';
  ```
- In the `app/assets/config/manifest.js` file, make sure that the builds directory is included:

  ```js
  //= link_tree ../images
  //= link_tree ../../javascript .js
  //= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js

  // Add the line below, with the double slashes and equal sign, followed by spaces.
  //= link_tree ../builds
  ```
- Don't forget to include assets in `assets.rb` file. Mentioned below in the comments on how to setup the same.

Comment: Hotwire/stimulus should be completely unrelatd

Comment: the problem appears to be that the cssbundling bootstrap installer (rails css:install) appears to only work for Importmap apps and does not produce the correct result for Jsbundling apps. I don't think any of the suggestions here work as expected

Comment: @JasonFB Hotwire/Stimulus is completely unrelated, yes, but switching from import maps to jsbundling/cssbundling would mean that there will be remnant files which will have to be cleaned first. What I know for sure is that this issue is related to assets pipeline, as I've encountered similar issues with Propshaft using Bulma and Material symbols. `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` is what you're probably looking for. Try this:
`Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("node_modules", "<your-library-directory>")`

Comment: thank you  I tried this unfortunately still no luck. the old instruction pre-CSSBundling (for using the bootstrap Gem) work by adding `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font")` to assets.rb. However, even in the new app (Jsbundling/CSSbundling), I Have tried various combinations of Rails.application.config.assets.paths settings and still same result

Comment: note: when you run `rails new Xyz --css=bootstrap --javascript=esbuild` what you get in config/initializers/asset.rb is `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font")`

Comment: SOLVE— it was my fault

Answer (score 2):

I had some major problems getting bootstrap 5.1.3 javascripts working in rails 7.0.2.4. Tooltips and dropdowns were intermittent.

Firstly always use [bin/dev](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4413912779538-How-do-I-run-a-Rails7-app-including-the-js-and-css-watchers-in-Rubymine-) to start the rails server in development (rather than the `rails server` command).

What I had to do to get javascript functionality back into my rails 7 app was go into `app/javascript/application.js` and change this

```js
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
```

to this

```js
import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
Turbo.session.drive = false
```

and everything began to work as expected!

#### References

- [Turbo docs](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails#navigate-with-turbo-drive) mention it
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71110271/events-not-loading-on-first-page-load-but-works-after-refresh) also mentions it
- [This](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/139) issue, and [this](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/pull/222) and [this](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/196) PRs.

---

#### Things you may also try

- Each time before starting the server, use these commands to clear everything:

```
rake assets:clean
rake assets:clobber
rake tmp:clear
```

- [Hard refresh](https://fabricdigital.co.nz/blog/how-to-hard-refresh-your-browser-and-clear-cache#:%7E:text=Chrome%20and%20Windows%3A,down%20Ctrl%20and%20press%20F5.) (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click on refresh) on every page load, or <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

Comment: You shouldn't need to disable turbo drive to get Bootstrap to work

Comment: @JasonFB you’re right. Thanks for the reminder. I’ll update this (attempted)  answer with an accurate one

Comment: @JasonFB in case it helps, I had a similar problem (trying to get bootstrap JavaScripts to work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74952586/5783745)’s what worked (note: as you point out, no need to disable turbo)

Comment: I think it's a bug in cssbundling rails setup: https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails/issues/113

Comment: @stevec-- I would readily believe that one might need `document.addEventListener("turbolinks")` to re-init popovers and stuff after Turbo renders, however, the rest of this should not be necessary. I think it's a problem with the cssbundling setup; I am able to get it all working fine if I don't use CSSbundinling and just stuck to Sassc-rails with manual configuration (as provided in GH issue)

Comment: @JasonFB thanks, I hope any bugs are squashed and docs are improved. I have nearly zero js knowledge and so find it painful and time-consuming to decipher such issues (even if they seem easy to those that grok turbo and js, which I don't yet). Good work creating the issue.

Comment: Hi @stevec, thanks for reminding that "always use bin/dev to start the rails server", it solved my problem. May I ask why "rails server" affect bootstrap? If I deploy my web on Amazon, will "rails server" still affect bootstrap?

Comment: @abcXYZ I’m pretty sure `bin/dev` is only necessary locally, and only because for certain asset pipeline tools (eg esbuild, and probably some others), they won’t automatically refresh your js/css if the server is started with `rails server`, but on your production app, it’s fine to use `rails server` since you wouldn’t ever edit js/css on a live app. If you want to ask this as a separate stack overflow question hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me can answer. Please feel free to link to this thread as I’d be interested to understand better too

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are using the right markup with Bootstrap 5.  The Bootstrap 4 markup won't work.  Specifically, the data attribute to find dropdown elements was changed to:

```
:data => { "bs-toggle" => "dropdown"}
```